# How to pass a parameter within two Spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a Spring controller that as return a redirection to another controller.

First looks like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/some-url", method =
{ RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })
public String test(final Model model)
{
    ... 
    return "redirect:http://someurl/checkout/response";
}
```

The second is hooking the call of the first controller so it looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/**/response")
public String handleResponse(@RequestParam final MultiValueMap<String, String> params, @Valid @ModelAttribute final Cyber cyber,
        final BindingResult bindingResult, final Model model, final HttpSession session, final HttpServletRequest request) throws CMSItemNotFoundException...
```

I am wondering how to pass the '@RequestedParam params'  and the Cyber object from the first controller to the second.

Answer (score 1):

If you additionally want these attributes to be erased automatically from the session after they where consumed, you can alternatively use FlashAttributes. For this you have to declare a RedirectAttributes parameter in method `handleResponse` and call `addFlashAttribute` on it. For example `addFlashAttribute("cyber", cyber)`. Those will be available as model attributes in the targeted controller and will be gone out of the session automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @SessionAttributes and send the model to another content.

For more [click here](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/understanding-spring-mvc-model-and-session-attributes/)

Answer (score 0):

Hi thank you guys I found a solution googleing your suggestion in this link :

http://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-redirectview-example-add-fetch-flash-attributes-redirectattributes-model-requestcontextutils

This is exactly my case.